# c++ file bad bit

Tags: c++, ifstream

when I run this code, the open and seekg and tellg operation all success.
but when I read it, it fails, the eof,bad,fail bit are 0 1 1.

What can cause a file bad?
thanks

---

```
int readriblock(int blockid, char* buffer)
{
   ifstream rifile("./ri/reverseindex.bin", ios::in|ios::binary);

   rifile.seekg(blockid * RI_BLOCK_SIZE, ios::beg);
   if(!rifile.good()){ cout<<"block not exsit"<<endl; return -1;}
   cout<<rifile.tellg()<<endl;

   rifile.read(buffer, RI_BLOCK_SIZE);

   **cout<<rifile.eof()<<rifile.bad()<<rifile.fail()<<endl;**

   if(!rifile.good()){ cout<<"error reading block "<<blockid<<endl; return -1;}

   rifile.close();
   return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: It's very helpful if you can format your code properly (as Evan Teran did for you) and use comments instead of "**" to highlight specific code (so that your code will still compile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [Apache C++ Standard Library User's Guide](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/29-1.html):

> The flag std::ios_base::badbit indicates problems with the underlying stream buffer. These problems could be:
>
> - Memory shortage. There is no memory available to create the buffer, or the buffer has size 0 for other reasons (such as being provided from outside the stream), or the stream cannot allocate memory for its own internal data, as with std::ios_base::iword() and std::ios_base::pword().
> - The underlying stream buffer throws an exception. The stream buffer might lose its integrity, as in memory shortage, or code conversion failure, or an unrecoverable read error from the external device. The stream buffer can indicate this loss of integrity by throwing an exception, which is caught by the stream and results in setting the badbit in the stream's state.

That doesn't tell you what the problem is, but it might give you a place to start.

Keep in mind the EOF bit is generally not set until a read is attempted and fails.  (In other words, checking `rifile.good` after calling `seekg` may not accomplish anything.)

As Andrey suggested, checking `errno` (or using an OS-specific API) might let you get at the underlying problem.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725714/why-ofstream-would-fail-to-open-the-file-in-c-reasons/1725770#1725770) has example code for doing that.

Side note:  Because `rifile` is a local object, you don't need to close it once you're finished.  Understanding that is important for understanding [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), a key technique in C++.

Comment: Thanks everyone, It turns out my buffer is not writable when I use this function.

Answer (score 3):

try old `errno`. It should show real reason for error. unfortunately there is no C++ish way to do it.