# What could cause a stream to enter the "bad" state?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

In C++, each stream has a `bad` bit:

> This flag is set by operations performed on the stream when an error occurs while read or writing data, generally causing the loss of integrity of the stream.

[*Source*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/bad/)

What would cause a stream to "lose integrity" and enter the `bad` state? This is not the same as the `fail` state, which most often occurs when an input stream attempts to store a value into a variable that cannot accept said value (such as attempting to store a string into an integer variable).

Note that this question is a more general form of [c++ file bad bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547355/c-file-bad-bit), which is specific to file input streams; this question is not an exact duplicate as it applies to both input and output streams in general.

Comment: Maybe a multibyte-encoded stream that encounters an invalid multibyte sequence?

Comment: @KerrekSB, that would likely set the `fail` bit, not the `bad` bit, since the stream could be recovered by `ios::clear()` and `ios::ignore()`.  This is simply a case of invalid input; I don't think that causes the stream to lose integrity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/bad) :

> The standard library sets badbit in the following situations:
>
> - Insertion into the output stream by `put()` or `write()` fails for any
>     reason.
> - Insertion into the output stream by `operator<<`, `std::put_money` or
>     `std::put_time`, could not complete because the end of the output
>     stream was reached (The facet's formatting output function such as
>     `num_put::put()` or `money_put::put()`, returns an iterator `iter` such
>     that `iter.failed()==true`)
> - Stream is constructed with a null pointer for `rdbuf()`, or
>     `putback()`/`unget()` is called on a stream with a null `rdbuf()`, or a
>     null pointer passed to `operator<<(basic_streambuf*)`
> - `rdbuf()->sputbackc()` or `rdbuf()->sungetc()` return `traits::eof()` to
>     `putback() or`unget()`
> - `rdbuf()->pubsync()` returns -1 to `sync()`, to `flush()`, or to the
>     destructor of `ostream::sentry` on a `unitbuf` stream
> - Exception is thrown during an I/O operation by any member function of
>     the associated stream buffer (e.g. `sbumpc()`, `xsputn()`, `sgetc()`,
>     `overflow()`, etc)
> - Exception is thrown in `iword()` or `pword()` (e.g. `std::bad_alloc`)

---

This may be one more reason to choose cppreference.com over www.cpluplus.com, see: 
[What's wrong with cplusplus.com?](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/cplusplus.com)

Comment: "Exception in an underlying I/O operation" sounds like a good lead. After all, iostreams were intended to be extended, and so it's perfectly conceivable that some user-supplied implementation throws exceptions deeper down.

Comment: The "intent" is for `badbit` to signal an actual input/output error.  The interface for `std::streambuf` doesn't allow for this, however; it either returns a `char` or `EOF`.  If you get an input error when reading from a `std::filebuf` (`read` returns `-1` under Posix), I would expect `std::filebuf` to throw an exception, because it has no other means of signaling the error.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Apache C++ Standard Library User's Guide](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/29-1.html). Two potential causes for a badbit are listed there. I quote:

**Memory shortage**: There is no memory available to create the buffer, or the buffer has size 0 for other reasons (such as being provided from outside the stream), or the stream cannot allocate memory for its own internal data.

**The underlying stream buffer throws an exception:** The stream buffer might lose its integrity, as in memory shortage, or code conversion failure, or an unrecoverable read error from the external device. The stream buffer can indicate this loss of integrity by throwing an exception, which is caught by the stream and results in setting the badbit in the stream's state.