# how to set the badbit of a stream by a customized streambuf

Tags: c++, stream, std

I've a customized `std::streambuf`. Something like:

```
class mybuf : public std::streambuf {
  ...
  virtual std::streambuf::int_type underflow() {
    if(eof) {
     return traits_type::eof();
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
  std::istream stream(new mybuf(...));
```

Setting the `eof` flag of the stream is done by returning eof on the `underflow()` function.

How can I set the `badbit` flag of the stream? Should the `overflow()` function throw an exception?

Comment: throw an exception, yes. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161728/what-could-cause-a-stream-to-enter-the-bad-state (or direct link to [`ios_base::iostate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing an exception is indeed the way to go.

Refer to the reference page for [`std::ios_base::iostate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate), and specifically this :

> The `badbit` is set by the following standard library functions:
>
> - ...
> - Every stream I/O function if an exception is thrown by any member function of the associated stream buffer (e.g. `sbumpc()`, `xsputn()`, `sgetc()`, `overflow()`, etc)
> - ...