# unable to open file using complete path in ubuntu with boost C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

Playing around wit *boost* library using ubuntu, with the following code the file *main.cpp* gets open and being printed but when I try to open some other file on some other location, it does not work.

Here is the code

```
std::string line;
boost::filesystem::ifstream file ("main.cpp") ;
if (file.is_open())
{
  while ( getline (file,line) )
  {
    std::cout << line << '\n';
  }
  file.close();
}

else std::cout << "Unable to open file"<< std::endl;
```

Here is the path that I am giving and its not working.

```
boost::filesystem::ifstream file ("/home/0circle/workspace/practice/main.cpp") ;
```

can someone tell me what could be the problem and how to cure it ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you just `ls -l /home/0circle/workspace/practice/main.cpp`?

Comment: `its not working` - What it means?

Comment: @0circle You should execute that command on your shell prompt.

Comment: its not working means ... it gives error _Unable to open file_

Comment: @0Circle, please verify if the file exists, using HAL's recommendation, using the ls command, as specified in the first comment!

Comment: @HAL .. thanks for the suggestion .. its working now !!

previously was doing it wrong .. human error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file exists and you have permissions for reading the file:

- execute in shell: ls -l /home/0circle/workspace/practice/main.cpp
- verify if you have read rights (first column of the output of the
  previous shell command). See [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm)!
- try to find out reason of failure: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725714/why-ofstream-would-fail-to-open-the-file-in-c-reasons/1725770#1725770)!